# Wordpress - How to disable all author link but keep name as text?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, author

I would like to know how can we disable all author links (single post, blog, ...) in a wordpress site but keep their name as text ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing:

```
get_the_author()
```

This will only show Author name and not associated link.